# split and store into list with an array variable in php

Tags: php, arrays, list, split

I have a number that is get from a web page, such that
$number=12-34-33-87-54-................ and so on.

$number may have two numbers like $number=12-34
or
it may have 3 numbers like $number=12-34-33
or
it may have more numbers like $number=12-34-33-87-54-.......... and so on.

I want to split it by '-' and want to store in an array.
like array(12,34,33,.....)

I used the code given below but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
$a=array();
list($a)=split('-',$number);
foreach($a as $v)
{
echo $v;
}
?>
```

Plz tell me how can i split this?

Comment: Google's [first match](http://bit.ly/PFb9DP)

Comment: @GeenHenk +1 for use of bitly to cover lmgtfy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$parts = explode('-',$number);
```

Comment: Please improve your answer to include explanation as to why this is the most appropriate solution.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future readers.

Answer (score 3):

Although `split()` is [depracated](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php), [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) will do the trick for you

```
<?php
$a=explode('-',$number);
foreach($a as $v)
{
    echo $v;
}
?>
```

It assumes that a `,` is the default, so you can use it on a CSV without having to specify.

Answer (score 2):

explode will return this array without any interfere from your side

```
$returnedArray = explode('-',$number);
```

this should work fine for you

Answer (score 0):

[Php explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is what you need here.

```
$arrayOfTokens = explode('-',$number);
```

explode returns an array of string, as stated in the documentation provided.